# Node.js Express - How to pass the API KEY to the public app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I added node and express to my project with dotenv to hide the API KEY I am using.
Everything works fine but I cannot see how to pass the `process.env.API_KEY` to be used app.js file.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env.API_KEY);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Starting server: http://localhost:3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

**app.js**

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
    if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
        initApp();
    }
});

const initApp = () => {...}
```

Comment: Values in `.env` are environment configuration and usually shouldn't be sent to the frontend. What is this `API_KEY` for?

Comment: @jabaa That's correct, it shouldn't be use in public, but does that mean I should make the api calls within the index.js instead?
Currently I am calling the api in the app.js

Comment: Yes, the backend should call the API.

Comment: What if it is a map api? I want to display a map. Should even that be called from the server? How? @jabaa

Comment: Why not? What's the difference? It's only data.